# Add request function to CRUD model that sends an email

Tags: c#

I have no background in programing, but my job wants me to learn. I have built a simple .asp mvc project that is a database of movies and such. I need a request form for a movie that can be filled out and if that movie is added then the client would be sent an email. Can anyone give me an idea on how I could accomplish this task. Thank you for anyone who has time to even point me in the right direction.

Comment: You need to get a book or follow a tutorial. Google is great for finding both.

Comment: also look at some free or inexpensive online courses. they are great help too. http://exercism.io/languages/csharp/about

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward to do … you need to:

- get data from form (seems you already have the form)
- check with db if movie added (use Entity Framework, or some other ORM)
- send email based on result (You can use services for this -- sendgrid, I think twilio does it, or you can just use an smtp client if you already have a server address) …

Search/learn for each of these individually to get your project complete.